# Which of these two expressions (related to primes) is greater: $\frac{\sigma{(n)}}{n}$ or $\sum_{p \le n}{\frac{1}{p}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Would it be $\frac{\sigma{(n)}}{n}$ or  $\sum_{p \le n}{\frac{1}{p}}$?

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: No idea if this could help, but : $$\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\prod_{p^\alpha\mid n\wedge p^{\alpha+1}\nmid n}\dfrac{\sigma(p^\alpha)}{p^\alpha}=\prod_{p^\alpha\mid n\wedge p^{\alpha+1}\nmid n}\dfrac{p^{\alpha+1}-1}{p^\alpha(p-1)}=\prod_{p^\alpha\mid n\wedge p^{\alpha+1}\nmid n}\dfrac{p^{\alpha+1}-1}{p^{\alpha+1}-p^\alpha}<\prod_{p^\alpha\mid n\wedge p^{\alpha+1}\nmid n}\dfrac{p}{p-1}<\prod_{p\le n}\dfrac{p}{p-1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Couple calculations show:

$n=6$:
$$\frac{\sigma{(6)}}{6}= \frac{1+2+3+6}{6} = 2 > \frac{31}{30} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} = \sum_{p \le 6}{\frac{1}{p}}$$

$n=7$:
$$\frac{\sigma{(7)}}{7}= \frac{1+7}{7} = \frac{8}{7} < \frac{247}{210} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} = \sum_{p \le 7}{\frac{1}{p}}$$

And just for fun $n=101$ you have
$$\frac{\sigma{(101)}}{101} = \frac{102}{101} < \frac{422113843906354093775418512493046577809}{232862364358497360900063316880507363070} = \sum_{p \le 101}{\frac{1}{p}}$$

but for $n=102$ you have
$$\frac{\sigma{(102)}}{102} = \frac{36}{17} > \frac{422113843906354093775418512493046577809}{232862364358497360900063316880507363070} = \sum_{p \le 102}{\frac{1}{p}}$$